# Rails: find_by_contents with conditions; syntax help please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, conditional-statements, ferret, acts-as-ferret

Looking to limit a find based on conditions in a Rails 2.0.2.

Find statement:

```
@employees = Employee.find_by_contents(params[:keywords].to_s, :include => [ :categories, :revisions, :approvals, :archives, :related_documents ])
```

Need to add a condition to limit find

```
:conditions=>["archived = '0'"]
```

Though this doesn't work

```
@employees = Employee.find_by_contents(params[:keywords].to_s, :include => [ :categories, :revisions, :approvals, :archives, :related_documents ], :conditions=>["archived = '0'"])
```

Anyone know what the syntax should be?

Comment: So what about exception? Which error?

Comment: what type of the `archived` field? Really `Strig`? Or `Boolean`?

Comment: No errors, has just ignored the conditions statement. boolean.

Comment: So why do you using :conditions=>["archived = '0'"] condition??? rather :conditions=>["archived = ?", false]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was having quite a time with adding a condition to ferret find_by, so I added a post command to filter if it's archived. If you think of a better way still, let me know. Thanks.

```
@employees = Employee.find_by_contents(params[:keywords].to_s, 
              :include => [ :categories, :revisions, :approvals, 
                            :archives, :related_documents ])
@employees = @employees.find_all {|p| !p.archived}
```

Comment: bad solution, because you can use only AR

Answer (score 0):

If you pass conditions an array, I think it needs to be for a parameterized condition. Try either/both of the following:

```
    @employees = Employee.find_by_contents(params[:keywords].to_s, 
                  :include => [ :categories, :revisions, :approvals, 
                                :archives, :related_documents ], 
                  :conditions=> "archived = '0'")
```

or

```
@employees = Employee.find_by_contents(params[:keywords].to_s,                           
                  :include => [ :categories, :revisions, :approvals, 
                                :archives, :related_documents ],
                  :conditions=>["archived = ?",'0'])
```

Comment: Neither of them were successful at limiting the results.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,  what error do you have?

And try this

```
@employees = Employee.find_by_contents(params[:keywords].to_s, :include => [ :categories, :revisions, :approvals, :archives, :related_documents ], :conditions=>["employees.archived = ?", false])
```

Comment: No error. It just ignores the conditions statement as if it wasn't there.

Comment: see update. use `:conditions=>["employees.archived = ?", false]`